# What are the 'header' lines/meta information in a formal letter called?

Tags: word-choice, letter

When writing a letter there is often meta information about the correspondence before the actual content of the letter. For example, in bold below:-

> Address,
> Town,
> City,
> Postcode
>
> 23rd July 2012
>
> **RE: Letter received 1st July 2012 
> Reference: [some ref]**
>
> Dear Mr Smith,
>
> ... Content here ...
> ...
> ..
> .

What is this section called?

Answer (score 3):

I'd call it "Reference" or "Subject."

Answer (score 1):

[About.com](http://www.about.com) refers to this as the **Reference Line**:-

http://jobsearchtech.about.com/od/letters/l/bl_mblock_p.htm